# android ArrayAdapter.clear() clears custom method variable

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` with a custom `ArrayAdapter where I update sometimes the values sometimes.
Everything works fine, but on the first update it becomes empty.

My array adapter:

```
protected class ResultArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JsonObject> {
    private ArrayList<JsonObject> values;
    protected ResultArrayAdapter(ArrayList<JsonObject> values) {
            super(context, R.layout.content_result_item, values);
            this.values = values;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { ... }
    public void updateValues(ArrayList<JsonObject> values) {
        //here values.size() > 0 and everything OK
        this.clear();
        //here values.size() == 0, why??
        for (JsonObject value : values) {
            this.add(value);
        }
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

When I update my values, I call `updateValues()` and after calling `this.clear()`, also the parameter `ArrayList<JsonObject> values` of this method is empty. So after this, there is no value to add with `this.add(value)`, but only after the first time of `onUpdate()`.

Also renaming the `ArrayList<JsonObject> values` parameter, or saving it in another one, does not help.

Comment: Because ArrayAdapter stores ArrayList references passed via constructor and clear method do clear on it(not always beware of filtering!!!) ... Also there is no need to notify the adapter after add as it's done in add method. Just instead update values use addAll method

Comment: I think is no correct "clear this", you should clear the ArrayList<JsonObject>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're updating the values with the same instance of the `ArrayList` you're setting with the constructor. You could surpass this by not setting the initial values from outside. Also you don't actually need the `values` member in your class.

```
protected class ResultArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JsonObject> {
    protected ResultArrayAdapter(List<JsonObject> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.content_result_item, new ArrayList<JsonObject>());
        updateValues(values);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { ... }
    public void updateValues(List<JsonObject> values) {
        this.clear();
        this.addAll(values);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Also you can use `addAll()` instead `add()` within a for loop and provide a `List` instead of an `ArrayList`. You could even choose `Collection` if you like.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { ... }
public void updateValues(ArrayList<JsonObject> newValues) {
    //here values.size() > 0 and everything OK
    values.clear();

    //here values.size() == 0, why??
    for (JsonObject value : newValues) {
        values.add(value );
    }

    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was: if I updated the arrayadapter with the values with it I initialized like:

```
ListView resultsView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.results);
ResultArrayAdapter adapter = (ResultArrayAdapter)resultsView .getAdapter();
if(adapter == null){
    adapter = new ResultArrayAdapter(MyActivity.this, values);
    resultsView .setAdapter(adapter);
} else {
    adapter.updateValues(values);
}
```

so `this.clear()` clears my values. e.g. i initialize my array adapter with values list 1, then I update with values list 2, so it wors, but updating with values list 1 again, it was empty.
My workaraound was a mix of your examples, so THX!

```
protected class ResultArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JsonObject> {
    private ArrayList<JsonObject> values;
    protected ResultArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JsonObject> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.content_result_item, new ArrayList<JsonObject>()); //passing new fake values
        this.values = values; //without this, it crashes
        updateValues(values);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { ... }
    public void updateValues(List<JsonObject> values) {
        this.clear();
        this.addAll(values);
    }
}
```